# Creating a signature box within a PDF document using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, signature

I know Adobe has an inbuilt signature field in which you can add to a PDF document. However I would like the signature field to be auto generated within the PDF document itself using a PHP script.

This is because the PDF document is generated on mass and mail merged for business reasons which is why I would like a script to automatically add the signature box rather than having to manually add on a signature box to each PDF one at a time. I have looked on loads of forums for an answer but with no luck thus far.

Basically, I am looking for a simple way to have a PDF with an inbuilt electronic signature box.

Comment: HI Alex, welcome to SO. Could you please share what PDF solution are you using? TCPDF, FPDF, or something else?

Comment: We have tried to use both TCPDF and FPDF and have not yet discovered a way to create a signature field using either of these libraries.

Comment: Here's an idea (I'm not sure how this would turn out). 1. Create a document with a signature box, using Adobe. 2. Then when you do the mass pdf generation, you use FPDI to import the page with the signature box as a template and you write/merge

Comment: @Eisenheim FPDI is not able to import content outside of a pages content stream. A signature field is an annotation + form field.

Comment: @JanSlabon thank you pointing that out, I did not know that. There goes my hypothetical solution lol. Thanks again